# CSS !important not working correctly on submit type

Tags: css, html

I know how CSS works but this little bit confuse.

I have button:

```
<input type="submit" name="button_name" id="button_id" value="Enter">
```

css file:

```
 #button_id 
{ 
  width: 50px !important; 
  font-size: 17px !important;
}
...
input[type=submit] 
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
  font-weight:bold!important;
  font-size:30px!important;
}
...
```

and button still have a with `300px` (should have `50px` because `!important` atribute) and `font-size 17px` because `#button_id` contains `font-size:17px!important;` 
How can i have with `50px` if `!important` not working? And why it working with `17px`?

Comment: need space `font-weight: bold !important`

Comment: space is not a matter

Comment: Well you have spelled `width` wrong... - https://jsfiddle.net/bemd779c/

Comment: @Paulie_D yes...... thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case you dont need to use !important just change the order of the css

```
input[type=submit] {
  width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:30px;
}

#button_id {width:50px; font-size:17px}
```

The last overwrites the first

Answer (score 1):

You spelled *width* wrong

```
#button_id {with:50px!important; font-size:17px!important;}
```

It should be:

```
#button_id {width:50px!important; font-size:17px!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the !important modifier

Simply add another CSS rule with !important, and either give the selector a higher specificity (adding an additional tag, id or class to the selector), or add a CSS rule with the same selector at a later point than the existing one (in a tie, the last one defined wins). [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cpxghbcq/)

Try to put you need to spelled `width`  correctly then  `#button_id {width:50px!important; font-size:17px!important;}`

```
bellow on your
input[type=submit] {
width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
  font-weight:bold!important;
    font-size:30px!important;
}
```